# "psql: warning: extra command-line argument" when attempting to run sql files from Windows cmd line

Tags: command-line-arguments, psql

I'm attempting to run this statement in the cmd prompt so that I can execute an sql script over a database.

```
"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\psql.exe" -U someUsername -h localhost someDbName -f "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\script.sql"
```

However, I'm getting back the error messages:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-f" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument
> "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\script.sql" ignored

New to all of this, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you enter `psql --help` you will see the following summary:

```
Usage:
  psql [OPTION]... [DBNAME [USERNAME]]
```

which means the database name must come after all "options", or it must be passed as an option (using `-d`)

So either:

```
psql.exe -U someUsername -h localhost -d someDbName -f "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\script.sql"
```

or

```
psql.exe -U someUsername -h localhost -f "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\script.sql" someDbName
```

Comment: After trying both queries, the cmd prompt gets stuck (I can't type anything) and nothing is returned. When I run the SQL in pgAdmin manually, I should get back a list of items

Comment: @displayName: maybe the missing `"` at the end of the filename in my answer? (copy & paste error)

Comment: No the string is indeed closed. I found out that if I replace the -f and sql path call with a direct command -c "Select * from table" it does indeed work. However that wasn't my original intention. Is there a way to call the sql file instead of manually typing the entire sql command?

Comment: @displayName: that should work with the command given. Why it's not working is a totally new question and can't be answered without the actual content of that file

Comment: strange... it is a single command. It is this exactly "SELECT name from testTable"

Comment: does it end with a `;`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include that in the quote. It does already end with ';'

Comment: In Linux, unlike Windows, psql parses correctly the command line arguments if the db is passed first (without -d) and the -f parameter later. Tested on CentOS7/psql 9.2 and Ubuntu 20/psql 9.6

Answer (score 2):

This was my workaround!

```
@ECHO OFF
set PGPASSWORD=postgres
psql -U postgres -f "C:\Users\projects\Project\drop_create_db.sql" -d postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Edi's method was what I used successfully, here is the same thing but with extra parameters.. I'm running this on a windows 10 client with psql shell installed, from a batch file against a greenplum database (postgres DW)

test.bat contents, p is port:

```
set PGPASSWORD=yourPW
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\psql.exe" -h instancename.blah.com -U scott -p 6420 -f "c:\temp\postgresversion.sql" -d dbnamehere
```

posgresversion.sql contents:

```
SELECT Version();
```